# Get incrementing Sequences c#

Tags: c#, sequence, increment

Given a simple List of integer already ordered such as "1,2,5,7,8,9" how could I get the first element of every subsequence, and how long it lasted?

Desired result would be something like :

- 1:2
- 5:1
- 7:3

How could I implement this in c#?

After some first thoughts i've came up with  this :

Being "horacitas" my sorted List with, for example the values "8,12,13,16,17,18":

```
   horacitas.Sort();
                    Dictionary<int, int> horas = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                    for(int i =0; i< horacitas.Count -1;i++)
                    {
                        int counter = 0;
                        int j = i;
                        while(horacitas[j+1]==  horacitas[j]+1 && j<horacitas.Count - 1)
                        {
                            counter++;
                            j++;
                        }
                        horas.Add(horacitas[i], counter);
                    }
```

But I encounter some problems, i end up adding to the dictionary unneeded entries for every item in the sequence, and not just for the starter one (for example, i end up with entries for 13,17,18).

Comment: Give as your code, we are not going (at least most of us) write code from zero. We help with your code, we do not make code from zero because your don't know how to make an alarm clock, you must have done something with that alarm clock and show us what you have done.

Comment: 1. Write a pencil-and-paper set of steps for your algorithm, whatever it is; 2. Write code that does that. If you find that parts of your pencil and paper algorithm are ambiguous, go back and fill in the parts you blew off. Lather, rinse, repeat, and in time you'll be a pompous bore like me. *At best.*

Comment: Edited after some tinkering!

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the loop. Each iteration, check if the current number is 1 higher than the last. If it is, add it to the sequence. If not, create a new sequence. At the end, print out each sequence.

You can store the "sequence" however you like. There are multiple ways to do it.

**EDIT:**
Now that you've provided code:

The problem you have is that your For-Loop is iterating over every single entry in your list. Your approach is to have an inner while loop to get each sequence. This is fine, but needs tweaking.

Try this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> horas = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for(int i = 0; i < horacitas.Count; i++)
{
    int counter = 1;
    while(i < horacitas.Count - 1 && horacitas[i+1] == horacitas[i]+1)
    {
        counter++;
        i++;
    }
    horas.Add(horacitas[i], counter);
}
```

Note: This approach will only work if no values repeat. For example, if you have the list "5,5", then it will error, because you can't add the "5" twice to the dictionary.

Comment: Wouldn't the first condition in the while statement make an error when i = count -1?

Comment: You're right! I must have overlooked that. We still want the for-loop to hit every number, though. Check out my revised answer.